# c# ip multicast receive and save multiple packets

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, udp, multicast

Hello i got this code  from [here](http://codeidol.com/csharp/csharp-network/IP-Multicasting/Csharp-IP-Multicast-Support/#part-6) to receive data on a multicast address

```
 Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
 Console.WriteLine("Ready to receive…");
 IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
 EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
 sock.Bind(iep);
 sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, 
            SocketOptionName.AddMembership, 
            new MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse("224.100.0.1")));
 byte[] data = new byte[1024];
 int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
 string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
 Console.WriteLine("received: {0} from: {1}", stringData, ep.ToString());
 sock.Close();
```

Now this works when i receive a packet, then the sock.ReceiveFrom is triggered but after that the receiver shuts down (even if i remove the sock.Close line).
What i want is that the receiver displays or saves me the data but continue listening for more packets.

What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to code some kind of loop or use the async methods BeginReceive/EndReceive.
As soon as your local sock variable gets out of scope, it might be collected by gc and get disposed.

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];

while (true) {
    // this blocks until some bytes are received
    int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
    string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
    Console.WriteLine("received: {0} from: {1}", stringData, ep.ToString());
}
```

Comment: so when using the while loop i assume to run it in an own thread, so maybe the BeginReceive method would be better to use?

Comment: That depends on the context. Receive is a blocking operation. When you have to do some other things in the meantime either span a thread and use the blocking while loop or use the async programming model with `BeginReceive/EndReceipt`